# Batch script line appears to be truncated

Tags: windows, batch-file

For my build system I export a batch file to re-generate the build graph if any of the build scripts change. The batch script doesn't run as expected, the command is seemingly truncated, or split in two.

```
@cd C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4
@call c:\users\niklas\repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\.venv\scripts\python.exe -m craftr.main -c --project C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\examples\c\build.craftr --variant debug -Oninja:_internal_regen=true -Oninja:_internal_regen=true -Oninja:_internal_regen=true -Oninja:speed=true --project examples/c\build.craftr --build-root build --pywarn none
@if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit %errorlevel%
```

This gives me

```
[.. output of command, WITH the flags below ..]
C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4>ld-root build --pywarn none
'ld-root' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The `--build-root build --pywarn none` options are actually passed to the command, but for some reason the batch processor tries to run `ld-root build --pywarn none` as a command as well. Why is that?

---

Update: It appears to be an issue with the double-colons in the `-O...` flags. Replacing these double colons with another character makes it "work" (obviously the command is incorrect then, but Batch executes it as expected).

Adding double quotes around the arguments does not help.

---

Update: Batch is a mystery -- it works for some reason now that I made sure that the `-Oninja:_internal_regen=true` flag is not added multiple times and removed the first `--project ...` argument (which was also incorrectly added anyway).

---

Update: While experimenting a bit more, I found another weird behaviour. The following runs fine:

```
cd C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4
call c:\users\niklas\repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\.venv\scripts\python.exe -m craftr.main -c --variant debug -Oninja:speed=true -Oninja:_internal_regen=true --project examples/c\build.craftr
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit %errorlevel%
```

And gives

```
C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4>cd C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4

C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4>call c:\users\niklas\repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\.venv\scripts\python.exe -m craftr.main -c --variant debug -Oninja:speed=true -Oninja:_internal_regen=false --project examples/c\build.craftr
Microsoft Visual C++ v141 (msvc) 19.14.26433 for x64
note: writing "C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\build\debug\build.ninja"

C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4>\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.backend\ninja\build.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\aliases\craftr.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.backend\ninja\ninja_syntax.py C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.backend\ninja\build_server.py C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\examples\c\build.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\aliases\cxx.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.lang\cxx\build.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.lang\cxx\impl\base.py C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.lang\cxx\impl\msvc.py C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.compiler\msvc.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.tool\batchvars.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.tool\cache.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.compiler\llvm.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.compiler\mingw.craftr OUTPUTS: C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\build\debug\build.ninja COMMAND: c:\users\niklas\repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\.venv\scripts\python.exe -m craftr.main -c --variant debug -Oninja:speed=true -Oninja:_internal_regen=false --project examples/c\build.craftr

C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4>if 0 NEQ 0 exit 0
```

But change `-Oninja:_internal_regen=true` to `-Oninja:_internal_regen=false` and it breaks apart.

```
C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4>cd C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4

C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4>call c:\users\niklas\repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\.venv\scripts\python.exe -m craftr.main -c --variant debug -Oninja:speed=true -Oninja:_internal_regen=false --project examples/c\build.craftr
Microsoft Visual C++ v141 (msvc) 19.14.26433 for x64
note: writing "C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\build\debug\build.ninja"

C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4>\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.backend\ninja\build.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\aliases\craftr.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.backend\ninja\ninja_syntax.py C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.backend\ninja\build_server.py C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\examples\c\build.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\aliases\cxx.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.lang\cxx\build.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.lang\cxx\impl\base.py C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.lang\cxx\impl\msvc.py C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.compiler\msvc.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.tool\batchvars.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.tool\cache.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.compiler\llvm.craftr C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\src\craftr\stdlib\net.craftr.compiler\mingw.craftr OUTPUTS: C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\build\debug\build.ninja COMMAND: c:\users\niklas\repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\.venv\scripts\python.exe -m craftr.main -c --variant debug -Oninja:speed=true -Oninja:_internal_regen=false --project examples/c\build.craftr

C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4>if 0 NEQ 0 exit 0
```

Note how the third call is garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try without the call.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4"
"c:\users\niklas\repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\.venv\scripts\python.exe" -m craftr.main -c --project "C:\Users\niklas\Repositories\craftr-build\craftr4\examples\c\build.craftr" --variant debug -Oninja:_internal_regen=true -Oninja:_internal_regen=true -Oninja:_internal_regen=true -Oninja:speed=true --project examples/c\build.craftr --build-root build --pywarn none
```

Comment: I'm a little bit puzzled as this works -- but for some reason the initial snippet I posted works too. :-X Anyway, I added another update where I found a little change makes it go haywire

Comment: The command that is run from the batch file actually rewrites the batch file. Could that be an issue?

Comment: What is the name of the batch file? Hopefully not the same as any command in the file.

Comment: Ok I think I found it. Ping-ponging the batch file seems to works. I.e. the build system generates a file `...regen_ping.bat`. If that batch file is called, it's goal would be to rewrite the batch file. But this time it generates a file `...regen_pong.bat`. The next time, it generates `...regen_ping.bat` and so on. This way we make sure the command run from the batch file does not rewrite the batch file itself.

Comment: ok, was about to say that, but also, please get rid of `call`.. use it as per my example.

Comment: On a side note, the batch script seems to randomly drop characters when the command line is too long. Know anything about that? Had quite a time finding the reason why the one command failed with characters missing in filenames :')

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's got nothing to do with the Batch syntax, but the fact that the command that was run from the batch file would actually rewrite the contents of the batch file itself.

Making sure that the file is not overwritten while it is being executed makes it work. I solved it by "ping-ponging" between two differnet filenames each time it is invoked (the caller knows about the correct file to invoke, too).

Comment: Though it can be done successfully, dynamically modifying a batch script is rarely a good solution. There is almost always a better way to solve the problem.